# Web scraping and promise with node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using cheerio and node to do web scraping. I thought it would be good idea to use promise for making it easier to deal with the asynchronous code. So, tried to chain the promises but could not make it working. I am pasting my code over here such that somebody could help me figure out what exactly I have been doing wrong.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
  loadPage().then(parseLoadedData);

}).listen(3000, function(error){
  console.log(error);
});


function fetchMainPage(){
  var deferred = q.defer();
  http.get('http://www.google.com?q=node', function(response){
      var responseString = '';
      response.on('data', function(data){
        responseString += data.toString('utf8');
      });
      response.on('error', function(error){
        deferred.reject(error);
      });
      response.on('end', function(){
        deferred.resolve(responseString);
      });
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}


function parseMainContent(responseString){
  var deferred = q.defer();
  var $ = cheerio.load(responseString);
  var rightCol = $('#right-col');
  var children = rightCol.children();
  var keys = Object.keys(children);
  var results = [];
  keys.forEach(function(key){
    var div = children[key];
    div.children.forEach(function(aChild){
      if(aChild.name == 'h3' && aChild.children[0].data == "Some title"){
        lis = aChild.next.children;
        var results = lis.map(function(li){
          var anchor  = $(li).find('a');
          if(anchor != undefined && anchor.attr('href') != undefined)
          return [anchor.text(), anchor.attr('href')]
        });
        results = results.filter(function(result){
            return result != undefined;
        });
        deferred.resolve(results);
      }
    });
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}



var loadPage = function(){
 return fetchMainPage().then(function(data){
    return data;
  })
},
parseLoadedData = function(data){
  return parseMainContent(data).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```

The problem here is I can't get my parseLoadedData being called. The response is fetched from the server but the second chaining does not seem to be working. I would like to thank you all in advance for helping me out.

Note: The url I am using is different and so the parsing function deal with that specific url only.

Comment: What is that `parseMainContent` function supposed to do exactly? It's definitely no good idea to try to `deferred.resolve()` in a loop…

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the `loadPage` function since `fetchMainPage` already returns a promise so this should work:

```
var loadPage = function(){
 return fetchMainPage();
}
```

To chain promises every `then` callback should return another promise and you were returning the `data`.
Eg.:

```
var loadPage = function(){
  var deferred = q.defer();
  fetchMainPage().then(function(data){
    return someOtherPromise(data);
  }).then(function(someOtherData) {
    return myThirdPromise(someOtherData);
  }).then(function(myThirdData) {
    return deferred.resolve(myThirdData);
  });
}

// IS THE SAME AS

var loadPage2 = function(){
  return fetchMainPage().then(function(data){
    return someOtherPromise(data);
  }).then(function(someOtherData) {
    return myThirdPromise(someOtherData);
  });
}
```